# Heroku / Rails - Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I try to access my API after deploying to Heroku, I keep getting this error and the application crashes. It uses PostgreSQL and I tried running a `rake db:migrate` beforehand as well. I tried a few other solutions with the same error but none of them were related to Heroku hosted apps.

I'm running heroku-20 stack with ruby 2.7.0. Bundler version 2.3.3.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

**Gem file:**

```
ruby '2.7.0' 

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
gem 'pg'

gem 'rake'

gem 'tiny_tds'
    
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Gemlock:**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.4.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
    activerecord (6.1.4.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
    activestorage (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.4.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    bootsnap (1.9.3)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    crass (1.0.6)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    ffi (1.15.4)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    i18n (1.8.11)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    listen (3.7.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.13.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    minitest (5.15.0)
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.12.5-x86_64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    pg (1.2.3)
    puma (5.5.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.1.4.4)
      actioncable (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      actiontext (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.4.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.13)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    spring (4.0.0)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stripe (5.42.0)
    thor (1.1.0)
    tiny_tds (2.1.5)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    zeitwerk (2.5.2)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-20

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.4)
  byebug
  listen (~> 3.3)
  pg
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rails (~> 6.1.4, >= 6.1.4.1)
  rake
  spring
  stripe
  tiny_tds
  tzinfo-data

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.7.0p0

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.3
```

While thew deploy is successful, the error happens only when I try to call an API or simply access the application URL. What could be causing this? I appreciate it!

Comment: You have database on heroku ?                                                                                              
`1. Add-ons: Heroku Postgres`
`2. heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Yeah. Almost looked like it was going to work with the migrate process starting and then ended with the same error: `Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources` @LihnNguyen

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`? Have you tried `bundle exec rake db:migrate`? Does your Gemfile have a `source` line that you just left out of the question? e.g. `source 'https://rubygems.org'`? What do you mean the "deploy was successful"? How are you deploying?

Comment: You check `gem list`. gem 'rake' exists ?

Comment: you're using spring 4.0. while not the optimal solution, try downgrading to 3.0. i ran into this issue after an upgrade. did not try 3.1 though. there must have been some change between 3.0 and 4.0 that causes this: https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md